Can I use Power BI to report on how long Azure DevOps work items spend in each state?
I am using Power BI to query work item data from Azure DevOps' Analytics Views. One of the things I'd like to do is produce a report showing how long work items are spending in different states e.g. New, Development, Testing etc.
To do this, I created an analytics view that pulls work item history from the API. The data model looks like this:



Work Item Id
State
Date
IsCurrent




1
New
14/08/2024
0


1
New
15/08/2024
0


1
Development
16/08/2024
1


2
New
15/08/2024
0


2
Development
16/08/2024
0


2
Done
20/08/2024
1


3
New
10/08/2024
0


3
Done
20/08/2024
1


4
New
10/08/2024
0


4
Development
11/08/2024
0


4
New
12/08/2024
1


5
New
10/08/2024
0


5
Development
10/08/2024
0


5
Done
10/08/2024
1



As you can see, there is an entry for each change that was made to the item, but the change made wasn't necessarily to change the state.
What I want is to group the data by Work Item Id and State, and produce a date difference field that shows how long each item spent in each given state. What I'm struggling with is that the time spent in a state e.g. Development is calculated by the difference between the date it first entered the development state, and the date it moved into the next state e.g. Done.
So, for the data above, what I'd be looking to get is something like this:



Work Item Id
State
Time (Days)




1
New
3


1
Development



2
New
1


2
Development
4


2
Done



3
New
10


3
Done



4
New
0


4
Development
0


4
Done




I can think of how I'd do this in a programming language I'm familiar with, but I'm new to Power BI. Is this in any way possible?
So far, I've tried using the RANKX function to assign each item a rank based on its Date and Work Item Id:
Rank = RANKX(
    FILTER(
        'DevOps History'
        , 'DevOps History'[Work Item Id] = EARLIER('DevOps History'[Work Item Id])
    )
    , 'DevOps History'[Date].[Date]
    , 
    , ASC
)

This ranks all the history entries for each Work Item Id by their date, but I can't get it to also group by State and I don't know how to then calculate the date difference between each.

I highly recommend checking out FlowViz. It provides a Work Item Age chart and many other useful visuals for project tracking.

Hi Ben, it seems Nick's answer can meet your needs to get the report of how long work items are spending in different states. You can try it and let us know if it works in your side.

If the problem is complicated due to states are not modified in the normal order,  you might consider using work item rules to restrict the states that can be selected.

First I summarized the DevOps History table to get a single date for each Work Item Id, State, IsCurrent, and Date.
From my experience a work item rarely goes straight from New->Dev->Done. It often goes from New->Dev->New->Dev->Done, so I added logic to get the first time a work item enters New and the last time it enters Dev/Done. Logic has also been added to retrieve the isCurrent status of a duplicate state.
Summarized History = SUMMARIZE('DevOps History', 'DevOps History'[Work Item Id], 'DevOps History'[State], 

    "IsCurrent", //If a state is visited multiple times, this gets whether it is currently active or not
    MAX('DevOps History'[IsCurrent]), 
    "Date", //If a work item goes from New->Dev->New->Dev->Done this step step gets the firt time it entered new and the latest time it entered Dev/Done

    IF(MAXX('DevOps History', [State]) = "New", MINX('DevOps History', [Date]), //First time work item entered New
        MAXX('DevOps History', [Date])) //Last time work item entered not New state

)

Then I created a States table for each State and the Order they appear in the board.
Note: This can be automated using this API



State
Order




New
1


Development
2


QA
3


Done
4



Connect States[State] to Summarized History[State] by a 1 to Many relationship.
On the Summarized History table, created a Calculated Column:
State Order = RELATED(States[Order])
Then I added a calculated column to this table to find the work item age:
Time (Days) (Updated) = 
//Get this rows data
VAR thisStateOrder = [State Order]
VAR thisDate = [Date]
VAR thisCurrent = [IsCurrent]
VAR thisID = [Work Item Id]

//find next state the workitem goes into
VAR workItemStates = FILTER('Summarized History', 'Summarized History'[Work Item Id] = thisID && [State Order] > thisStateOrder) //Get all states that are not current state or previous state
VAR workItemNextState = MINX(workItemStates, [State Order]) //Get next state in order
VAR workItemNextStateTable =FILTER(workItemStates, [State Order] = workItemNextState) //filters table to just the next state in order

//find the date of the next state
VAR nextStateDate = MAXX(workItemNextStateTable, [Date])

//find the age of current state
VAR TimeDays = IF(thisCurrent <> 1,
    DATEDIFF(thisDate, nextStateDate, DAY),
    BLANK()
)

RETURN TimeDays

Input DevOps History:



Work Item Id
State
Date
IsCurrent




1
New
07/14/2023
0


1
New
07/15/2023
0


1
Development
07/16/2023
1


2
New
07/15/2023
0


2
Development
07/16/2023
0


2
Done
07/20/2023
1


3
New
07/14/2023
0


3
Development
07/17/2023
1


4
New
07/16/2023
0


4
Development
07/18/2023
0


4
Done
07/21/2023
1


5
New
07/17/2023
0


5
Development
07/19/2023
0


5
Done
07/22/2023
1


6
New
07/17/2023
0


6
Development
07/19/2023
0


6
Done
08/15/2023
1


6
New
07/23/2023
0


6
Development
08/01/2023
0


7
New
07/17/2023
0


7
Done
08/01/2023
1


8
New
07/17/2023
0


8
Done
07/19/2023
0


8
Development
07/23/2023
0


8
Done
08/11/2023
1



Output Summarized History:



Work Item Id
State
Date
IsCurrent
State Order
Time (Days) (Updated)




1
New
07/14/2023
0
1
2


1
Development
07/16/2023
1
2



2
New
07/15/2023
0
1
1


2
Development
07/16/2023
0
2
4


2
Done
07/20/2023
1
4



3
New
07/14/2023
0
1
3


3
Development
07/17/2023
1
2



4
New
07/16/2023
0
1
2


4
Development
07/18/2023
0
2
3


4
Done
07/21/2023
1
4



5
New
07/17/2023
0
1
2


5
Development
07/19/2023
0
2
3


5
Done
07/22/2023
1
4



6
New
07/17/2023
0
1
15


6
Development
08/01/2023
0
2
14


6
Done
08/15/2023
1
4



7
New
07/17/2023
0
1
15


7
Done
08/01/2023
1
4



8
New
07/17/2023
0
1
6


8
Development
07/23/2023
0
2
19


8
Done
08/11/2023
1
4





This got me a long way towards what I want to do, with one exception. It's actually possible for items to skip states e.g. going straight from 'New' to 'Done' - that's my bad, my test data didn't cover that - and in this instance I think nextState will be blank even though there's a "later" state to jump to...
I think what I'd need to do to cover this case is to keep looking for a matching value in the next state until one is found, unless isCurrent is true?

@BenOsmond I updated my answer to solve for this extra scenario. If this works for your problem, please accept this answer as accepted. Thank you.
